# how to select jquery dom and if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm new to jQuery.. can anyone tell me the right syntax for this.. it should check if those two input fields has a value.. if it has it says yes in the div called 'status'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($("one'").val()) &&($("two").val()){

    $("status").text (Yes);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Some errors in your code:

- IDs and classes are used in jQuery as they are in CSS. Hence, you'll need `#` to select IDs and `.` to select classes.
- If you want to return a string you need to wrap it in quotes. If you just put `Yes`, jQuery will look for a variable that is called so.
- In an if-function, the whole thing is surrounded by parentheses, not the different requirements seperately.

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#one").val() && $("#two").val()) {
        $("#status").text("Yes");
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/jU9Mf/)</kbd>

Even though I would guess you want to check the inputs every time they change, so fire that function when the inputs change:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
        if ($("#one").val() && $("#two").val()) {
            $("#status").text("Yes");
        }
        else {
            $("#status").text("");
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/jU9Mf/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please show your html, but lets say your selectors one, two and status are classes

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        if($(".one").val() != '' && $(".two").val() != ''){
            $(".status").text ("Yes");
        }
    });
```